# Adding padding to HTML elements - IE, FF, Chrome etc

Tags: html, css

I've a doubt. Lets consider that we have a div of width 200px. If i add the following the style

```
style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px"
```

to the element what happens actually? Will the total width of the div increases to 220px with 10px at the left (for left padding), original width 200px at the middle and 10px at the right (for right padding)?

Or will it takes the padding space from the 200px and becomes (10px + 180px + 10px)?

Does the above rendering differs for each browser (especially IE and FF)?

**Update**

```
<div style="width:180x">    
<div style="width: 180px;background-color: #4E81BD;text-align: left;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;">
    <a class="anchor-tag" href="Javascript:;"><span style="font-family: Calibri,Tahoma,Verdana;font-weight: 500; color: white">Rasu</span></a>
</div>
<div style="width: 180px;height: 270px;border: 1px solid #4E81BD;padding: 5px;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #DADADA;height: 150px;overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: auto;text-align: left;font-family: Calibri;">
    </div>
    <div style="height: 10px;">
    </div>
    <div style="height: 75px;border: 1px solid #DADADA;">
        <textarea>[Type your message here]</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you

NLV

Comment: In newer browsers you can choose the model you want to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All modern browsers conform to the W3C box model. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) for details. Here's a diagram demonstrating how the overall dimensions of a box are calculated:

[image]

Essentially the dimensions of a box are `width` + `padding` + `border`. The margin is not added to the width, although it may affect the box's positioning.

Philippe is correct about IE5, which has a broken box model.

If you'd like to alter the way the box model works, you can use the `box-sizing` CSS3 attribute, though at this stage you'll have to also use `-webkit-box-sizing`, `-ms-box-sizing` and `-moz-box-sizing` to ensure that the different browsers all pick up the value.

More details here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: But i'm not getting the above markup to work correctly in IE7 and FF 3.5.*. Any insights?

Comment: If the box model is behaving other than what you're expecting, you probably have other stray styles interfering with what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

It will become 220px wide.

In IE5 or IE6 (quirks mode), it will be 10px+180px+10px, but I wouldn't worry about that.

The full story can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: I've placed two divs one below the other inside a parent div all measuring 180px wide. I've set the border to be 2px and left, right padding to be 5px for the lower div. In IE7 it is getting rendered correctly whereas in FF 3.5.* it is failing (missing out the border 2+2 px). Any ideas?